# Realm Notification listener crash when scrolling to the end

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I am using realm db to represent a UITableView the DB is so dynamic it will change or modify every milli second.

I am listing to the notifications like this mentioned in their documentation.

```
extension UITableView {
    func applyChanges<T>(changes: RealmCollectionChange<T>) {
        switch changes {
        case .initial: reloadData()
        case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let updates):
            let fromRow = {(row: Int) in
                return IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)}

            beginUpdates()
            deleteRows(at: deletions.map(fromRow), with: .automatic)
            insertRows(at: insertions.map(fromRow), with: .automatic)
            reloadRows(at: updates.map(fromRow), with: .none)
            endUpdates()
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

myTableViewViewController.swift

// In ViewDidload

```
_ = dbfiles?.observe(self.tableView.applyChanges)

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell") as! MyCell
        if indexPath.row <= (dbfiles?.count)! {
     // update cell info 
}

return cell
```

when I scroll to end or repeatedly I am getting crash as below

```
    @throw RLMException(@"Index %zu is out of bounds (must be less than %zu).",
                        e.requested, e.valid_count);
```

suggest me how can I gracefully handle this.